# Chern-Weil homomorphism and classifying space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, equivariant-cohomology

Let $G$ be a real or complex Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$, and let $\mathbb C[\mathfrak g]$ be the algebra of $\mathbb C$-valued polynomials on $\mathfrak g$. Denote by $$\mathbb C[\mathfrak g]^G=\{f\in \mathbb C[\mathfrak g] | ~f(Ad_g x)=f(x),~ \forall g \in G,~ \forall x\in \mathfrak g\}$$
the subalgebra of fixed points in $\mathbb C[\mathfrak g]$ under the adjoint action of $G$.

Now, given principal $G$-bundle $P$ on a manifold $M$, the *Chern-Weil homomorphism* is an homomorphism of $\mathbb C$-algebras $\mathbb C[\mathfrak g]^G \to H^*_{dR}(M, \mathbb C)$, which is given by $f\mapsto f(F_\nabla)$ for some connection $\nabla$ on the given bundle.

Suppose $G$ is compact, then according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Weil_homomorphism#Definition_of_the_homomorphism), we have an isomorphism of $\mathbb C$-algebras $$\mathbb C[\mathfrak g]^G \cong H^*_{dR}(BG, \mathbb C) $$

**Question:** Is this isomorphism given by the Chern-Weil homomorphism?

If so, a problem is that $BG$ may fail to be a smooth manifold, so additional conditions should be needed. And, what $G$-bundles on $BG$ should be taken into consideration? And, can we construct explicitly the inverse homomorphism?

If not, how to understand this isomorphism?

Comment: Yes. $BG$ isn't a smooth manifold, but it's a union of them.

Comment: $BG$ is a smooth stack, and Chern-Weil theory can meaningfully be understood as describing its de Rham cohomology. See Freed and Hopkins https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.5959 for details.

Comment: A down-to-earth description of $BG$ as a simplicial manifold, its simplicial de-Rham-cohomology and characteristic classes can be found in Dupont's textbook "Curvature and Characteristic Classes" .

Answer (score 2):

> Is this isomorphism given by the Chern-Weil homomorphism?

Yes, see Theorem 7.20 in [the paper of Freed and Hopkins](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.5959),
which computes the de Rham complex of B<sub>∇</sub>G
as C[g]<sup>G</sup> equipped with the zero differential.

Some important remarks:

1) B<sub>∇</sub>G is the stack of principal G-bundles *with connection*.
Connections are necessary to define the Chern-Weil homomorphism.

2) The statement already holds on the level of chain complexes,
not just individual cohomology groups.

3) B<sub>∇</sub>G is not a smooth manifold, but a stack
(namely, a simplicial presheaf) on the site of smooth manifolds.